# Multiprocessing apply_async with over million processes becomes slower

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Now I try to compute some heavy calculation called `test()` using `apply_async` from `multiprocessing` module.
The results are stacked in the dictionary called `pool_out` with callback function `log_result`.

However, when I run over a million jobs to `apply_async`, it takes too much time to enqueue to the `pool`, and the time increases quadratically with the number of jobs as follows:

```
from os import cpu_count
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
from time import time

def test(i):
    return i + 10
def log_result(i, result):
    pool_out[i] = result

pool_out = {}
pool = Pool(cpu_count())
t = time()
try:
    print("i\t total queue size \t enqueue time")
    for i in range(10000000):
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print(str(i) + "\t\t" + str(pool._taskqueue.qsize()) \
                  + "\t\t (%.3f sec)"%(time() - t))
            t = time()
        if i not in list(pool_out.keys()):
            pool.apply_async(test, args=(i,), callback=partial(log_result,i))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pool.terminate()
```

Output:

```
i    total queue size    enqueue time
0       0        (0.001 sec)
10000       9986         (0.061 sec)
20000       19974        (0.060 sec)
30000       29967        (0.048 sec)
40000       39959        (0.054 sec)
...
2000000     1983601      (1.890 sec)
2010000     1993429      (1.873 sec)
2020000     2002977      (1.966 sec)
```

[image]

So how can we limit the number of queue waiting for executing in `pool`?

---

**Here what I have tried.**

It is trivial that the problem can be solved if I reduce the number of jobs.
So, I can chunk the number of jobs using

```
for j in range(100):
    pool_out = {}
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    for i in range(100000*j, 100000*(j+1)):
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print(str(i) + "\t\t" + str(pool._taskqueue.qsize()) \
                  + "\t\t (%.3f sec)"%(time() - t))
            t = time()
        if i not in list(pool_out.keys()):
            pool.apply_async(test, args=(i,), callback=partial(log_result,i))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

instead of

```
for i in range(10000000):
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print(str(i) + "\t\t" + str(pool._taskqueue.qsize()) \
              + "\t\t (%.3f sec)"%(time() - t))
        t = time()
    if i not in list(pool_out.keys()):
        pool.apply_async(test, args=(i,), callback=partial(log_result,i))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However, it does not seem to be a neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if i not in list(pool_out.keys()):
```

to:

```
if i not in pool_out:
```

This becomes a bigger and bigger inefficiency. What should be an O(1) operation (more or less) is an O(N) operation (and space inefficient) the way you are doing it and N gets very large after a while.