# Hawkes process simulation and central limit theorem

Tags: python, statistics, cython, simulation, montecarlo

First of all, I apologize that if this question is too mathematical or statistical, but I have no idea where should I ask this kind of question, so I ask here.

Now I am trying to implement my own **Hawkes process simulation** by following Ogata's thinning algorithm (see Algorithm 3 of [this](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Eychen/research/Thinning%20algorithm.pdf)) and the python package [`tick`](https://github.com/X-DataInitiative/tick).

So first I consider the standard exponential kernel Hawkes process as follows: (in jupyter notebook)

```py
%load_ext Cython
```

```py
%%cython -a
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdlib cimport srand, rand, RAND_MAX  # RAND_MAX = 2147483647
from libc.math cimport pow, abs, log, sqrt, exp, M_E as e

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef double rand_unif():
    cdef:
        double u;
    
    u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)
    return u

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef double rand_exp(double lamb):
    """Inverse-transform method"""
    cdef:
        double u;
    
    u = rand_unif()
    return -log(1- u) / lamb

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef generate_Hawkes_Exp(double baseline, 
                          double alpha, 
                          double beta,
                          long int seed):
    srand(seed)
    cdef:
        double lambda_bound_t = 0
        double t = 0, t_before = t, dt = 0, u = 0
        double lambda_t = 0, excitation_t = 0, int_Hawkes_t = 0
        long int i = 0
        double[:] points = np.zeros(int(4*baseline/(1-alpha/beta)))  # 4x buffer
        
    while t < 1:
        lambda_bound_t = baseline + alpha*int_Hawkes_t
        t_before = t
        dt = rand_exp(lambda_bound_t)
        t += dt
        if t >= 1:
            break

        int_Hawkes_t *= e**(-beta*dt)
        excitation_t = alpha * int_Hawkes_t
        lambda_t = baseline + excitation_t
        
        # Acceptance-rejection method
        u = rand_unif() * lambda_bound_t
        if u < lambda_t:  # accept
            points[i] = t
            i += 1
            int_Hawkes_t += 1
            
    return np.asarray(points[:i])
```

Here, for simplicity, I only considered the time range from `t=0` to `t=1`.

But now I recognize that my simulation does not give the correct central limit result for the number of points.
By [Bacry et al (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04592), when `alpha = n`, `beta = 2n`, `baseline = n`, its expected number of points should be `2n` with variance `2^3 n`.
However, the following Monte Carlo simulation does not yield the result.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

N_sim = 100
ns = np.array([10**4, 10**5, 10**6, 10**7])

def log_out(i, out):
    pool_out[i] = out

def run(seed):
    """This will be run in parallel."""
    print(seed, end=': ')
    t1 = time()
    outs = []
    
    for n in ns:
        baseline = n*1.
        alpha = n*1.
        beta = n*2.
        
        points = generate_Hawkes_Exp(baseline, alpha, beta, seed)

        outs.append(len(points))
    t2 = time()
    print("%.3f sec"%(t2-t1))
    return outs

pool_out = {}
pool = Pool(cpu_count() - 2)
try:
    for seed in range(N_sim):
        if seed not in pool_out:
            pool.apply_async(run, args=(seed,), 
                             callback=partial(log_out, seed))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pool.terminate()
pool_out=dict(sorted(pool_out.items()))

data = np.array(list(pool_out.values()))
normed_data = ns**(-1/2)*(data - 2*ns)/np.sqrt(2**3)
pd.DataFrame({'Mean': normed_data.mean(0), 
              'Std':normed_data.std(0)},
             index = pd.Series(ns, name='n'))
```

| n | Mean | Std |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 0.240 | 1.003 |
| 100000 | 0.204 | 0.972 |
| 1000000 | 0.368 | 1.058 |
| 10000000 | 0.965 | 1.001 |

As you see above, while the CLT tells us that the Mean should go to zero,  the simulation result does not.
So the question is

> **Question**: Where did I make a mistake in `generate_Hawkes_Exp`? Since when `n` is small, it gives a quite reasonable result, so it looks like some small precision errors are magnified when `n` is very big.

Notice that `tick`'s function `SimuHawkes` gives the correct result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Possibly use `log1p(-u)` instead of `log(1-u)`? That's designed to be more accurate for small values of `u`

Comment: And `exp(-beta*dt)` instead of `e**(-beta*dt)`

Comment: Still, the result is exactly the same. In my opinion, `rand_unif` and `rand_exp` may be ok.

Comment: And `if seed not in list(pool_out.keys()):` looks like a horrendous race condition (or does nothing... I'm not sure)

Comment: Plus you seem to forgotten [this answer someone already gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63872111/4657412)

Comment: Oh, thank you for the comment! You are correct that the searching algorithm is very inefficient, although it is not related to the original issue.